# как создать метод который выводит сумму мин и макс з масива php

Tags: php

Как создать метод который выводит сумму мин и макс з масива php

```
  public function  get_array_min() {
        $min = null;

         foreach ( $this->oop as $k => $v ) {
             if ( $v < $min or $min === null ) {
                 $min = $v;
             }
         }
         return $min;
   }


   public function get_array_max() {
        $max = null;

         foreach ( $this->oop as $k => $v ){
             if ( $v > $max or $max === null ) {
                 $max = $v;
             }
         }
         return $max;
   }
```

нужно из этого сделать метод

Comment: Метод чего? Метод сам по себе не существует, он должен кому то принадлежать

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: нужно сделать метод который выводит сумму мин и макс з масива

Comment: `public function sum_array_min_max() { return $this->get_array_min() +  $this->get_array_max(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали, какой массив нужно использовать, поэтому я предположу, что это массив $this->oop.

Метод get_array_min_and_max выводит минимальную и максимальную сумму из массива:

```
public function get_array_min_and_max() {
        $min = null;
        $max = null;

        foreach ( $this->oop as $k => $v ) {
            if ( $v < $min or $min === null ) {
                $min = $v;
            }
            if ( $v > $max or $max === null ) {
                $max = $v;
            }
        }

        return array('min' => $min, 'max' => $max);
}
```

Comment: Что из приведенного вами, является методом?

Comment: @SwaD Метод - это функция или процедура, которая принадлежит классу или экземпляру класса, к сожалению у меня нет полного кода класса для того что бы обернуть данную функцию в метод :) По моему предположению Michail просто теряется в определениях.